# How should one maintain/support old answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing-help

Over a period of 4 years, I have answered a lot of questions on SO, and occasionally I get a down-vote on an old answer, which was valid at the time, but now better solutions/approaches exist, or should be updated to newer versions (of rails in my case mostly).

So what do people? Do they actively maintain the quality of their answers? I mostly notice when I suddenly get a down-vote and then, indeed, in most cases a better answer is already available.

What do you do in that case? Edit/improve your original answer? Credit the better answer? Delete the answer? I had the best answer in 2011, in 2012 a better answer comes along, in 2014 I get a downvote: how to handle that :) Just ignore it?

My general approach, in case of a downvote is to edit/update the answer, but I only respond to downvotes, I have no pro-active approach.

Comment: How you maintain your old answers is entirely up to you.  I'm not particularly proactive about it; if someone points out a problem with one of my old answers, I'll either try to fix it or, if it has become completely obsolete, I'll just delete it.

Answer (score -5):

I am having the same problem. I keep getting downvoted for an answer on jQuery I gave back in 2013. It was valid back then.

Why should I maintain my answers from 7 years ago? It was valid back then and got a lot of upvotes. Not only would it require extra effort that isn't worth it, it would no doubt become irrelevant to the original question. It's not my problem if the answer has become invalid over time and the person reading it can't see it from an eternity ago.

My suggestion is to disable downvoting for really old questions. Obviously that has drawbacks and implications, but it's better than nothing in my opinion.

Additional thoughts based on Cody's comment: Votes are literally tied to a "Reputation" system. So a downvote is a ding on one's reputation. A content rating system, such as one applied here on meta, where people upvote to say they agree, or downvote to express that they disagree (or it has quality issues), but those votes do not impact reputation.

If you were a stockbroker, and you gave your friend advice 10 years ago about a hot stock, but they waited until last year to act on that advice and they ended up losing big. Now they are mad at you. Should your reputation be tarnished because your advice was no longer valid several years later?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to disable downvoting for old answers? A downvote means “this answer is not useful”. It sounds like you’re granting that it’s not useful because it’s out of date. That’s a perfectly valid reason to downvote. Actually, such posts *should* be downvoted as a signal to others that they are obsolete and no longer useful. Downvoting isn’t a punishment. It’s a content rating system. Content that is wrong is...not useful. Votes that have historical meaning only are not productive for anyone.

Comment: @CodyGray You say it's a content rating system, which I don't disagree with, but if that's all it is, then why reward users for the upvotes? If the content is no longer useful, why even have it available for searching? The signal should be the fact that it's a 7 year old question/answer. If I had 15 votes and the user downvoted once, it sits at 14 which still looks like a good answer, so it makes no sense.

Comment: @CodyGray I added more to my answer in response to your comment. Too long to put into a comment.

Comment: I don't really see gaining reputation points as a "reward". They mostly grant you access to more janitorial duties on the site. It's a privilege, not a reward. By the same logic, losing reputation points is not a punishment. It's all just balancing of the books.

Comment: @Gimby Now we're debating the significance of the rep system? At one point your SO reputation was considered during a job interview, just as your GitHub account is today. It's more than just a number referring to your custodial engineering level. How many questions would go unanswered if not for reputation? You can't sit back and say that reputation doesn't hold sway in the decision process for users. I certainly care less about rep now than I did back in the day, but that doesn't mean I want the work I did previously to be discounted because it's not relevant today.

Comment: @Gimby by the logic put forth by yourself and Cody, among others from responses to similar questions I've seen, at some point, we would all fall back to 0 rep given enough time and "passers by" who downvote. Why even have a rep system then?

Comment: Please delete your wrong answer or fix it. Otherwise you're being part of the problem not part of the solution. A big problem with the internet as a whole is searching and getting lead to outdated info. Take some responsibility and help make the world a better place. Either fix your outdated answer (best), edit it with a warning at the top "no longer correct ignore", or delete it. .... or except that the downvotes you're getting are entirely because your outdated answer is actively making the world a worse place.

Comment: @gman So it's my responsibility to make sure people who can't pay attention don't get incorrect info from a 7 year old answer? If providing answers to questions ends up making me "part of the problem" then there's no reason to participate in SO, is there? Saying that my answers, which were helpful and accurate at the time of posting, are now making the world a worse place is the most asinine thing i've seen said thus far. Why doesn't SO just hide or delete old questions and answers if that's the case? Wouldn't SO be the biggest offender since it's archiving such terrible content?

Comment: An old answer can be the correct answer and an old answer can be wrong. Wrong answers should be downvoted. The downvote is a signal to clean up the answer. This is no different than the real world. You can plant a garden (good) and let it rot (bad). I have no issue with any answer I've left that's no longer correct to be downvoted. Either I will fix it or ignore it and accept that people are correctly marking it as bad because it is bad. It's hard to understand why it bugs you that your wrong answer is getting downvoted. It's wrong now is all that matters, not that it used to be correct.

Comment: I'm also not here to mine for points, I'm here to help people. Wrong answers are not helpful even if many years ago they were right answers. I can choose to clean them up or I can choose to ignore the downvotes. I won't get upset by them though as downvoting wrong answers is exactly the purpose of downvotes. (OTOH I do get upset when I get a downvote for a right answer )

Comment: Lately I asked a short question that was flagged as duplicate of a convoluted question of multiple pages of code and was answered equally complex. My question and answer would not take more that a few lines. Quality of the answered question hence was low. As SO ages this problem will increase. As it is not possible to curate all old q/a at least reluctance to close a good question in favour of a bad past answer should be observed. Some sort of arbitrage for mark for duplication would be helpful at this stage.