# Is it good practice to edit one's own old posts?

Tags: discussion, edits, old-answers

I've been around for awhile, and have a lot of love and respect for SO and what it stands for. It is still quite rewarding to log in some afternoons and see the green +10 telling me that I helped someone somewhere.

I recently got involved moderating low quality posts, and doing so got me thinking about my best-voted answer. [Using Linq to get the last N elements of a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453274/using-linq-to-get-the-last-n-elements-of-a-collection/3453301#3453301)

Now, by current standards, this is a low-quality post. I mean, it isn't, because it helped lots of people. But it is because it lacks description, explanation, and rich content to make it more search-friendly. I'm glad it was helpful, but it deserves to be better quality.

I want audit my own profile for similarly sparse posts, not to change the intent or correctness of the post, but to bring them up to the current standards of SO. What is my concern, though, is that the answer helped people *as it is* and it was accepted by the OP *as it is*. And the question has been as it is for four and a half years.

So, to my question: Is it considered a good, bad, or an indifferent practice to revisit one's own old posts, particularly one's own accepted answers, and edit the content. Is the benefit of improving the content considered to outweigh the importance of the history and context in which the answer or question was framed? The SO help center states "Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it"; however, is it appropriate to do so for very old content?

In some ways, this question is similar to [How should one maintain/support old answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/how-should-one-maintain-support-old-answers); but different in the sense that I am not especially interested in preserving reputation or correcting obsolete answers. What I want to do is improve the quality, not necessarily the "correctness" of the posts. In this way, I would think that editing the posts is at worst harmless and at best useful, unless it is the opinion here that old posts carry historical significance as they stand.

Comment: Only if you have the time and they get better. But given that SO also has a long term function (serve knowledge to all visitors), yes, no reason not to.

Comment: Improving a post (no matter if new or old) is a valuable contribution to the community, IMO.

Comment: Yes, definitely. The only proviso is don't edit old posts too often, as it brings them to the front page each time you do so.

Comment: Only caveat I'd offer is don't materially alter questions, such that subsequent answers appear 'wrong'.  Amending answers to make them clearer or add new information is generally good.

Comment: "Never stop improving." Even if its a old answer, if you can improve it by explaining something or adding content, do it. If it helps someone at some point, it was worth it, IMO.

Comment: I make a practice of always reviewing a question or answer of mine that gets upvoted, to see if I can improve it. Knowing that people are looking at it gives me motivation to improve it.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be good practice to improve anything?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Maybe he's concerned about bumping old content. I seem to recall something about that being frowned upon.

Comment: @canon, indeed that was a concern of mine, though not one that I discussed explicitly in my question. Based on the overwhelmingly positive feedback on updating old posts, it looks like that is not a problem. Thanks, all.

Comment: I absolutely agree with everyone else that if you can make it better, then do it.  Even if the technical details are still "correct," it's also possible that you've just become a better writer since that answer, give clearer explanations, have a broader approach or application to a wider range of cases, added bacon to it, etc. (have not looked at the original question or answer, these are just meant as representative examples of cases where improvements to the original would definitely be warranted).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Sure. If you see room for improvement, improve it!

Your answer, as it stands, is great because it gets right to the point - don't lose that! But, if you were to add a paragraph explaining briefly why it works - and why some of the suggestions in comments *don't* work - that'd be a boon to readers wishing to quickly gain a better understanding of the technique as well, without compromising the directness of the existing answer.

Comment: The second part of your answer is the problem - the original answer might be special in some way that your "improvement" will destroy, without your even being aware of it. When I edit my old answers I try to add to them rather than changing the existing wording.

Comment: Right - unless there's a glaring *problem* that you need to fix (tons of people leaving confused comments, an actual change to how what you're explaining works, etc.) you should try to ***build on* your existing answer** rather than replacing it.

Answer (score 9):

My primary motivation in answering questions on StackOverflow was to give back to the SO community for the help I had received from it.  However, over time, I realized that there was a side benefit -- my answers can show prospective employers that I actually have the skills that I tell them I have.  Because of that I've tried to make sure that my answers are of good quality, and also that my comments and interactions with others are civil and diplomatic.

I think it is OK to benefit a bit this way from the work I've put in, and as such, if I did have an old answer that could be improved without losing the original goodness of the answer (as Shog9 points out), then I think it's OK to make the improvement.