# Outdated answer

Tags: discussion

I just stumbled over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition) which had been answered 2012. At that time the answer was probably correct, but today the standard has changed and the answer is definitely no longer (completely) correct. I would not care too much, but there are a lot of people upvoting it (probably still) just because they think the answer is correct. So SO is actually promoting (now) wrong answers this way. The person that answered even does not react on another fail in his answer since March. The next top voted answers are also wrong regarding the current standard.

Adding my own answer seems pointless since there are already 38 and who would seek the truth at the very bottom? I wouldn't. I even gave up after reading the first 3 answers and seeing them wrong in the same aspect.

There's [another question here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268490/how-should-one-maintain-support-old-answers) which is similar to mine but it has no answer. Any takers?

Comment: This confusion is exactly what the "Outdated Answers" project is attempting to solve right now - until it gets up to speed, do basically what you think is the best thing to do. It might sound odd, but there *are* people who would wade through 38 answers to find the best and/or the most relevant one - and promoting the latter is exactly what's in scope of the "Outdated Answers" project should you decide to answer, at some point you will see an increased "return" on your contribution if the project succeeds

Comment: Post about it on meta, link to the answer, and hope meta users upvote it? Have you tried that yet? Oh wait...

Comment: What answer are you referring to? The [highest scored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition/10394722#10394722) (a deleted answer has nearly as many upvotes)? Or do you mean all the answers?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The one left on top. The one you mentioned might have been delete because of that very issue (though a simple edit might have sufficed). The answer really hurts me...